A card strategy game.
Alice has a deck of $52$ cards (half of which are black and the other half red) and shuffles the cards in any way she wishes. Bob then selects a natural number
$n$ such that $0 \leq n \leq 52$ and splits the deck into the first $n$ cards and the remaining $52 - n$ cards. He shuffles the cards from these two piles in such a way that the relative order within each pile is preserved in the final deck. (In other words, he takes the two piles and for each card, chooses which pile to take the bottom card from to place into the newly formed deck, the first card is obviously the bottom card from some deck). Alice does not see how Bob merges the two piles; she only knows the number $n$. After the merging, Bob returns the deck to Alice, and then Alice begins to turn over the cards one by one from the top of the deck. Before each card is turned over, she announces whether she wants to guess the color of the card. If she announces a guess and guesses the color correctly, she earns a point; if she announces a guess and guesses incorrectly, the game ends. How many points can Alice guarantee?
I found this problem while reviewing my old Olympiad combinatorics course from a few years ago. I have solved it already, but I forgot the solution, I only remember some parts, so I can give a few things I remember being useful. First, I tried smaller cases. It helps a lot with understanding the problem. Next, remember Alice can shuffle two decks any way she wishes, so I thinked in steps, how can she guarantee guessing the first card? Pretty obvious, she can make the top cards the same color. I got stuck at that, but I believe it is a bit different for all other cards, but the same thinking. Maybe?

Bob can select any $n$, so Alice cannot garantee to guess the 1st card.

How? Alice just makes the top cards of both decks the same color. One of these cards has to be on the top of the full deck of cards, it would be a contradicition if it was other color.

Bob split the deck in $n$ cards and $p=52-n$ cards. The 1st card of 2nd subset is the card which was originally at rank $n+1$ ; When she shuffles the deck, Alice doesn't know $n$ ; she cannot  decide to put same color in rank $1$ and rank $n$.

Oh, I understand what you're trying to say. I think you're right. Yes, my strategy is wrong.

To clarify, can Alice pass? You say that she "she announces whether she wants to guess the color of the card", but don't say what happens if she doesn't want to guess.

Alice should alternate Black and Red Cards, starting with Black for example.
She can garantee 26 guesses.
If $n$ is even, she will be able to garantee the $1$st guess (Black), and all cards with an odd rank. She will even be able to guess the 52th card, of course.
And if $n$ is odd, she will be able to garantee all cards with an even rank.
Edit:
We can write a number on each card, this number is the rank when Alice gives the deck to Bob. All Black cards have a number which is odd, all red cards have a number which is even.
If $n$ is even, we are sure that $1$st card will be black. It can be the card with number $1$ or $n+1$ ; let us consider it was n°$1$.
If second card is red, we are sure that this card has n°$2$, so next one will be n°$3$ or n° $n+1$, both of them are black.
And if second card is black, we are sure that this card has n° $n+1$; so next one will have n° $2$ or $n+2$, and both of them are red.
At rank $2k+1$, Alice just need to know the color of card at rank $2k$, and the next one will be the other color.
If $n$ is odd, it is similar, except that Alice will be able to guess cards with rank even, with same rule : what is the color of card at rank $2k-1$, next card will be the other color.
Edit n°2 :
Maybe there is a better strategy, but I don't think so !
Edit n°3, to explain this approach, with more mathematical terms :
Alice put the cards , alternate the colors, starting with black.
Let us consider the case where $n$ is even. Bob has created 2 subsets $A$ and $B$, both of them starting with a black card.
In both subsets $A$ and $B$, all cards with an even rank as red, all other cards are black.
At any time, let $n_A$ and $n_B$ denote th number of cards already displayed from subset $A$ and $B$.
When total number of displayed cards is even, $n_A + n_B$ is even, so $n_A$ and $n_B$ have same parity.
If the last card that was displayed is red, it may come from subset $A$, and in this case, $n_A$ is even. Or it may come from subset $B$, and in this case, $n_B$ is even.
But we know that $n_A$ and $n_B$ have same parity, so both $n_A$ and $n_B$ are even.
So the next card will automatically have a rank which is odd, so it is black.
And with very similar arguments, we can always guess every 2nd card.

Ah, I think I understand what you're getting at, but you'd need a bit more details to explain your idea. (I'm editing your writeup to remove my downvote.)
